# Gravity formula explanation needed

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Why, in finding gravity, are the masses of two objects multiplied? I don't understand the value of mass over gravity and why the masses are multiplied and then divided by radius^2. In one sentence I don't understand the idea of the gravity formula.
$F=Gm_1m_2/r^2$

Comment: It's an empirical law. That's just how the universe is...

Comment: ^ that. Through experiments, we determined that the amount of gravitational force any body exerts on another is proportional to the product of the masses of the bodies and the inverse of the square of the distance between them. The Cavendish experiment further allows us to narrow the constant of proportionality to $G$. There is some mathematical reasoning that supports the idea of an inverse-square law for gravity, but basically this mostly came from people doing experiments and noticing patterns.

Comment: Modern physics has more theoretical/mathematical reasoning, but it was built that way because of what we observed

Comment: It is a result of observations

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2008021/11127

Comment: It is an empirical result that came out of observations. You can read the related chapter from Feynman Lectures vol-1 to understand the logic.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can think of the force of gravity as something proportional to mass and inversely proportional to the distance squuared.

Basically, as I'm sure you know, the earth orbits the sun, because the sun has more gravitational force than the earth does, because of its increased mass. More mass means a greater force. That's why, as in the formula, Gravity = G(constant)*m1*m2/d^2 where as m1 or m2 increases, so does Gravity.

You also know that as distance increases, the gravitational force decreases. This explains why the Sun has a greater gravitational force on the Earth than on a planet from another galaxy.

All this can explain the formula, but as previously stated, it is an empirical law - we just know that the universe operates this way, not really why.

Comment: This is wrong! According to Newton the gravitational force is inversely proportional to the **square of the distance** d.

Answer (score -1):

The surface area of the sphere is proportional to the square of radius. So the flux of matter in gravitational field is inversely proportional to the square of radius.

Answer (score -2):

This is a fundamental thought. Glad to see you are thinking of reason behind mathematics. Let us limit this discussion to the inverse square law. We know that there is more advanced theory that reduce to inverse square law in specific simple conditions. I am only explaining why masses are multiplied in the simple case.

**m1*m2**

Per explanation of the law by Newton, every mass in the universe attracts every other mass. Now consider the first mass made of m1 very small fundamental unit particles and second mass made of m2, same mass fundamental particles. The fundamental particle here is just a convenience and not necessarily a fundamental particle per standard model. It can be, a proton for example. Each particle of mass1 (m1 particles) attracts each particle of mass2 (m2 particles) with certain tiny force. Now think how many such tiny attractions are there to add to come up with total attraction? It is exactly m1*m2. That is why the masses are multiplied - i.e. in broad common sense - to add up attraction between the two masses. As the number of particles would be proportional to the mass itself, so it is equivalent to multiplying the masses.

**r squared**

This arises due to the three dimensional geometry - the surface area of 3D sphere is proportional to r squared. This is because the space is curved and it can be curved only through the surface of the sphere passing through center of mass of the two bodies. More surface area to curve through means more space to be curved, means lesser the extent of the curve given the masses. And so inversely proportional to square of the distance.